# knife vsphere requests root password - is unattended execution possible?

Tags: bash, shell, chef-infra, knife, vsphere

Is there any way to ruyn the knife vsphere for unattended execution?  I have a deploy shell script which I am using to help me:

```
cat deploy-production-20-vm.sh 
#!/bin/bash

##############################################
# These are machine dependent variables (need to change)
##############################################
HOST_NAME=$1
IP_ADDRESS="$2/24"
CHEF_BOOTSTRAP_IP_ADDRESS="$2"
RUNLIST=\"$3\"

CHEF_HOST= $HOSTNAME.my.lan

##############################################
# These are psuedo-environment independent variables (could change)
##############################################
DATASTORE="dcesxds04"

##############################################
# These are environment dependent variables (should not change per env)
##############################################
TEMPLATE="\"CentOS\""
NETWORK="\"VM Network\""
CLUSTER="ProdCluster01" #knife-vsphere calls this a resource pool
GATEWAY="10.7.20.1"
DNS="\"10.7.20.11,10.8.20.11,10.6.20.11\""

##############################################
# the magic
##############################################
VM_CLONE_CMD="knife vsphere vm clone $HOST_NAME \
      --template $TEMPLATE \
      --cips $IP_ADDRESS  \
      --vsdc MarkleyDC\
      --datastore $DATASTORE \
      --cvlan $NETWORK\
      --resource-pool $CLUSTER \
      --cgw $GATEWAY \
      --cdnsips $DNS \
      --start true \
      --bootstrap true \
      --fqdn $CHEF_BOOTSTRAP_IP_ADDRESS \
      --chost $HOST_NAME\
      --cdomain my.lan \
      --run-list=$RUNLIST"

echo $VM_CLONE_CMD
eval $VM_CLONE_CMD
```

Which echos (as a single line):

```
knife vsphere vm clone dcbsmtest --template "CentOS" --cips 10.7.20.84/24
--vsdc MarkleyDC --datastore dcesxds04 --cvlan "VM Network"
--resource-pool ProdCluster01 --cgw 10.7.20.1
--cdnsips "10.7.20.11,10.8.20.11,10.6.20.11" --start true
--bootstrap true --fqdn 10.7.20.84 --chost dcbsmtest --cdomain my.lan
--run-list="role[my-env-prod-server]"
```

When it runs it outputs:

```
Cloning template CentOS Template to new VM dcbsmtest
Finished creating virtual machine dcbsmtest
Powered on virtual machine dcbsmtest
Waiting for sshd...done
Doing old-style registration with the validation key at /home/me/chef-repo/.chef/our-validator.pem...
Delete your validation key in order to use your user credentials instead

Connecting to 10.7.20.84
root@10.7.20.84's password:
```

If I step away form my desk and it prompts for PWD - then sometimes it times out and the connection is lost and chef doesn't bootstrap.  Also  I would like to be able to automate all of this to be elastic based on system needs - which won't work with attended execution.

Comment: The correct solution is to set up `ssh` so that you can log into the remote host without a password.

Comment: Another issue: don't use `eval` to run the command; instead, store the options in an array.

Comment: How do you set SSH up for that when the machine is being spun up as a VM from nowhere?  In the template?

Comment: Probably? That's a whole other question, one that is not on topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea I am going to run with, unless provided a better solution is to have a default password in the template and pass it on the command line to knife, and have chef change the password once the build is complete, minimizing the exposure of a hard coded password in the bash script controlling knife...

---

Update: I wanted to add that this is working like a charm. Ideally we could have changed the centOs template we were deploying - but it wasn't possible here - so this is a fine alternative (as we changed the root password after deploy anyhow).